# Facebook auth and JWT

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, jwt, facebook-oauth

Correct me if I'm wrong or someone can give me a guide about this. I'm working on an Ionic app with Laravel as a backend REST API.
A User can log in with credentials (email, password) or with Facebook.
Of course I wanna protect some states in the App as usual, and searching and reading in the web came across with JWT.

The thing is I'm little confused about how Facebook Oauth and JWT are working together.

So, here's what I'm trying to do:

If a user logs in with FB, get the id, nickname, email and creates a user with this information, also insert into a table this credentials from facebook so when it logs again check if the user already exists.
Then, this new user gets access to the app via JWT from the server, am I right??
Or how the auth token from facebook causes problem with the jwt token?? Or it will not??

Am I doing too much to resolve maybe a little problem?? Or is just the tip of the solution??

Thanx for your support.

Answer (score 0):

The tokens shouldn't conflict. The process should be the "same" in both cases - the jwt is generated from an user instance/model.
How you create/get this instance is not important - from credentials, facebook token, cookie or what ever you like.
The jwt just includes an unique identifier - the id.